# Web notifications, which highly trafficked sites web sites are using them? (A list of...)

Tags: web, push-notification, e-commerce, web-push

I'm evaluating to add in my company's web site web push notifications and I want to study some "production" cases.
I didn't find any important e-commerce, social network or simple web site that use web push (e.g Facebook, eBay, Amazon)
Could you help me to find a list of highly trafficked sites that adopted web notifications?

Many thanks.

Comment: Facebook uses web push notifications... You can see it as soon as you log in with Google Chrome. Also YouTube supports them. Large news websites use them. Also it really depends on what "highly trafficked" means: there are websites with millions of notification subscribers that are not "famous". Also consider that all native apps use notifications... so why not use them when you build a PWA?

Comment: Are you sure that YouTube supports web push?  If you want, share these less famous website, thanks!